# Error inserting two query in once by php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data in two tables, with exploiting the the primary key of the first one and add it as foreign key in the second table,i think the problem is the two query are inserting each info in the same time and it give us a conflict between foreign key and primary one,any ideas ? maybe making something like a delay between each query !!

```
<?php 
        $InputCIN = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"CIN");
        $InputID_PAYEMENT = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"ID_PAYEMENT");
        $InputDATE_PAYEMENT = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"DATE_PAYEMENT");
        $InputTYPE_DE_PAYEMENT = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"TYPE_DE_PAYEMENT");
        $InputPRIX = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"PRIX");
        $InputMOIS_PAYEMENT = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"MOIS_PAYEMENT");


                     $queryAj2_1 = "insert into payement values($InputID_PAYEMENT,'$InputDATE_PAYEMENT','$InputTYPE_DE_PAYEMENT',$InputPRIX,'$InputMOIS_PAYEMENT')";
                     $queryAj2_2 = "insert into payer values('','$InputCIN',$InputID_PAYEMENT)";
                          if(isset($_POST['butAj2']))//submit button
                     {
                         if($InputID_PAYEMENT && $InputCIN)
                         {
                      if(mysqli_query($con,$queryAj2_1) && mysqli_query($con,$queryAj2_2))
                        {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'><span class='fa fa-square-check'></span>Adding successfull</div>";
                        }


                    else
                    {
                    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><span class='fa fa-square-check'></span>Erorr adding</div>".mysqli_error($con);
                    }
                         }


                        else if(!$InputID_PAYEMENT && !$InputCIN) 
                        {
                              $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><span class='fa fa-square-check'></span>ADD CIN/ID PAYEMENT</div>".mysqli_error($con);
                        } 

                              else{
                              $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><span class='fa fa-square-check'></span>erorrrrrrrrrrrrr</div>".mysqli_error($con);
                        }//it show me this msg

                     }
>
```

Comment: You need to get the new key generated from the first query to use as the FK in the 2nd.

Comment: you can fire the second query on success of first query

Comment: "it give us a conflict between foreign key and primary one". Specify the exact error message - would help to know which key it is, and which tables and fields the key is defined on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mysqli_multi_query()` function performs one or more queries against the database.

**The queries must be separated with a semicolon**.

from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

> MySQL optionally allows having multiple statements in one statement
>   string. Sending multiple statements at once reduces client-server
>   round trips but requires special handling.
>
> Multiple statements or multi queries must be executed with
>   mysqli_multi_query(). The individual statements of the statement
>   string are separated by semicolon. Then, all result sets returned by
>   the executed statements must be fetched.
>
> The MySQL server allows having statements that do return result sets
>   and statements that do not return result sets in one multiple
>   statement.

```
$queryAj2_1 = "insert into payement values($InputID_PAYEMENT,'$InputDATE_PAYEMENT','$InputTYPE_DE_PAYEMENT',$InputPRIX,'$InputMOIS_PAYEMENT');";
$queryAj2_2 = "insert into payer values('','$InputCIN',$InputID_PAYEMENT)";

// Execute multi query
if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $queryAj2_1. $queryAj2_2))
{

// print message on success
```

Use of the multiple statement with **prepared statements** is not supported.

Comment: @medo100000S it seams like inputcin values aren't null but it fails to enter if condition

Answer (score 0):

You can Try the code below to fire multiple query in PHP.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO requestdetails (`userid`, `dayte`) VALUES ('$userid','$date');INSERT INTO managerrepo (`userid`, `dayte`) VALUES ('$userid', '$date') ";

if($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo "You have requested successfully!";    
    unset($_POST);
    //header("location: index.php?id=".$id);
} 
else 
{
    echo "Problem in request. Try Again!";  
}
```

OR

you use the below code too, for insertion in same table:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO requestdetails (`userid`, `dayte`) VALUES ('$userid','$date')";
    $sql_new  = "INSERT INTO requestdetails (`userid`, `dayte`) VALUES ('$userid', '$date') ";


if($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    if($conn->multi_query($sql_new) === TRUE)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "Problem in request. Try Again!";  
}
```

Comment: i did it man thanks the problem was my inputs are in defferent <form> tags

Answer (score 0):

There is been conflict when you are trying to execute both the query at the same time. The 2nd table does not able to take the reference of the 1st tables primary key.
Try this out....

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$queryAj2_1))
{
    if(mysqli_query($con,$queryAj2_2))
                        {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'><span class='fa fa-square-check'></span>Adding successfull</div>";
                        }
}
```

So, here there will be no chance of conflict and primary key will be inserted first into the table and then it's foreign key.